# HTTPS access to Tomato admin page

Tags: router, https, tomato

Today in Tomato administration interface I switched access method to the interface from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. The router (OVISLINK AirLive WL-1600GL) restarted itself and currently an attempt to connect results in:

```
An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.1.254.
SSL peer rejected a handshake message for unacceptable content.
(Error code: ssl_error_illegal_parameter_alert)
```

(Firefox)

```
SSL connection error
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

(Chrome)

Blame on me, I should have switched to `HTTP & HTTPS` first. And I don't even recall the exact Tomato version I have.

Any suggestions on how I could make it work?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to it via https?  What about if you put https:// 192.168.1.254:443 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting via https://192.168.1.254:443. http or port other than 443 gives different error message (webpage not accessible). So the service is definitely there, it just rejects my attempt to connect for some reason.

Comment: Having quite a few of devices, I tested most browsers under different os, with same result everywhere... except for *links* (wow!), which allowed me to connect and authenticate. However, it couldn't handle javascript that admin site used so I was unable to do anything...

Comment: Have you tried to scan 192.168.1.254 with nmap?  If so, could you post the results of nmap -vv -A 192.168.1.254

Comment: @Richie086: Thanks for this hint! I just discovered there was a telnet daemon running I wasn't aware of, so I could just log in and restore HTTP access for web interface. And here's full output: http://pastebin.com/xdCYzngE.

Comment: Mind if I write up an answer to the question since I led you to the solution?

Comment: Sure, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: hey I answered, please mark as being the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP was having an issue with his Tomato (modified router software) router.   He enabled HTTPS connections for the web interface for the Tomato router, but for some reason he could not connect to the admin interface over https if he went to https://192.168.1.254 or http://192.168.1.254 and was wondering how to change the setting back to allow both HTTP and HTTPS connections to the admin interface.

I suggested running the following nmap (network scanner) scan to see what the results were in regard to the HTTP/HTTPS responses that his router was sending back.

`nmap -vv -A 192.168.1.254`

Where -vv is Very Verbose (more information from scan) and -A is All (meaning do all standard network probes on the target).

The result was the OP realized that telnet (port 22/tcp) was open.   The OP was able to connect to the router via Telnet and reset the admin interface setting to allow for connections via HTTP and HTTPS.

So if you are in a similar situation, try a nmap scan on your Tomato router to see what ports are open.   Hopefully you also have telnet open and will be able to login and configure the router that way.